# In SQL Server I need to change data structure of relationships (FK)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Ok I wasn't entirely sure what to title this question, so here's the situation.

I'm big on data integrity... Meaning as many constraints and rules that I can use I want to use in SQL Server and not rely on the application.

So I have a website that has a business directory, and those businesses can create a post.

So I have two tables like this:

```
tbl_Business ( BusinessID, Title, etc. )
tbl_Business_Post ( PostID, BusinessID, PostTitle, etc. )
```

There's a FK relationship for the column BusinessID between the two tables. A post cannot exist in the tbl_Business_Post table without the BusinessID existing in the tbl_Business table.

So pretty standard...

I've recently added classifieds to the site. So now I have two more tables:

```
tbl_Classified ( ClassifiedID, SellerID, ClassifiedTitle, etc. )
tbl_Classified_Seller ( SellerID, SellerName, etc. )
```

What I'm wanting to do is take advantage of my tbl_Business_Post table to include classifieds in that as well. Think of its usage like a feed... So the site will show recent posts from businesses and classifieds all in one feed.

Here's where I need guidance.

I was tempted to remove the FK relationship on the tbl_Business_Posts...
I thought about creating another separate Posts table that holds the classifieds posts.

Is there a way to make a conditional FK relationship based on a column? For example, if it's a business posting the BusinessID must exist in the Business table, or if its a classifieds post, the SellerID must exist in the Seller table?

Or should I create a separate table to hold the classifieds posts and UNION both the tables on the query?

You might question why I have a "Posts" table and that's hard to explain... but I do need it for the way the site is organized and how the feed works.

It's just that the posts table is perfect and I wanted to combine all posts and organize them by type (Ie: 'business', 'classified', 'etc.') as there might be more later.

So it comes down to, what's the best way to organize this to sustain data integrity from SSMS?

Thank you for guidance.

======== EDIT =========

Full explanation of tbl_Business_Post

```
PostID PK
Post_Type int <-- 1-21 is business types, 22 for classified type
BusinessID INT <-- This is the FK currently for the tbl_Business
SiblingID INT <-- This is the ID of the related item they're posting on. So for example, if they post a story about one of their products, this is the ProductID, if it's a service, this is the ServiceID.
Post_Title <-- Depending on the post, this could be a Product title, a service title, etc.
```

So if I changed the structure so it's as follows:

```
PostID PK
Post_Type int
BusinessID INT <-- this is populated on insert if it's a business.
SellerID INT <-- This is populated on insert if it's a classified seller
SiblingID INT <-- This is either the classifiedID or ProductID, SeviceID, etc. Depending on post type.
```

So leaning toward Peter's 1st solution/example... interested in the proper way to create check constraints or triggers on this so that if the type is 1-21, it makes sure BusinessID exists in the Business table, or if it's type 22, make sure the SellerID exists in the seller table.

Even going further with this:

If Post_Type = 22, I should make sure that not only is the Seller in the seller table, but the SiblingID is also the ClassifiedID in the Classified table.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding your data structure, but in my thinking, a classified is a type of post, so why not make the tbl_Classified table link to tbl_Business_Post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) There's no way to do this kind of conditional FK you're thinking of. What you need here is basically a FK from tbl_Business_Post which points logically to one of two tables, depending on the value in another column of tbl_Business_Post. This situation is what people encounter quite often. But in a relational DB this is not a very native idea.
So OK, this cannot be enforced with a FK. Instead, you can probably enforce this with a trigger or check constraint on tbl_Business_Post.

2) Alternatively, you can do the below.

Create some table tbl_Basic_Post, put there all columns which pertain to the post itself (e.g. PostTitle) and not to the parent entity which this post record belongs/points to (Business or Classified). Then create two other tables which point via a FK to the tbl_Basic_Post table like e.g.

tbl_Business_Post.Basic_Post_ID (FK)
tbl_Classified_Post.Basic_Post_ID (FK)

Put in these two tables the columns which are Business_Post/Classified_Post-specific
(you see, this is basically inheritable in relational DB terms).

Also, make each of these two tables have FKs to their respective parent tables
tbl_Business and tbl_Classified too. Now these FKs become unconditional (in your sense).

To get business posts you join tbl_Basic_Post and tbl_Business_Post.
To get classified posts you join tbl_Basic_Post and tbl_Classified_Post.

Both approaches have their pros and cons.
Approach 1) is simple, does not lead to the creation of too many tables; but it's not trivial to enforce the data integrity.
Approach 2) does not require anything special to enforce data integrity but leads to the creation of more tables.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I'm leaning toward the first solution. My tbl_Business_Post has a column called (Post_Type) which holds an integer value. There are multiple types of business posts, 21 actually, which keep it organized and easy to query for particular types of posts. Lets say I add another type (22) for classifieds. Can you show me an example of setting up check constraints for something like this? So if it's type BETWEEN 1-21 it checks against the tbl_Business, and if it's type 22 it checks against tbl_Classified? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm going to edit my question to include more thorough table information... one moment :)

Comment: Please see my edit made to original question. Thank you Peter.

Comment: Check constraint is easy: just check that Post_Type is in the set of possible values.

Comment: Trigger on INSERT/UPDATE: based on the Post_Type which the trigger sees, inner join to the respective sibling table and check if you have at least 1 record in the sibling table with the value of SiblingID (if yes, you allow the insert/update to proceed, if no - you raise an error in the trigger and thus the orphan record (which breaks the data integrity rules) won't be inserted/updated).